# sqlalchemy - query.all() - list of tuples to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

This is my call: `session.query(User.username, User.first_name, User.last_name).all()`

It returns: `[('myUsername', 'myFirstname', 'myLastname')]`.
 

I want that to be the following format:
`[{"username":"myUsername", "first_name":"myFirstname", "last_name":"myLastname"}]`

I tried with `[dict(zip(["username","first_name","lastname"], x))]`
But it returns this: `[{'username': ('myUsername', 'myFirstname', 'myLastname')}]`

Comment: By the way you have enough rep to vote now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing returned has a single entry containing a tuple, you need to convert that to a list:

```
In [123]:
[dict(zip(["username","first_name","lastname"], list(temp[0])))]

Out[123]:
[{'first_name': 'myFirstname',
  'lastname': 'myLastname',
  'username': 'myUsername'}]
```

In my code example above it just has a single entry, so in the general case you would need to iterate over whatever `session.query().all()` returns and populate your dict.

Comment: yeah, that temp[0] in my case should be a for, if multiple tuples appear, got it: `[ dict( zip(("username","firstname","lastname"),y)) for y in x]`

Comment: Sorry my temp was this in my IDE like this `temp = [('myUsername', 'myFirstname', 'myLastname')]` so in your case you need to iterate over the results of whatever is returned from `session.query().all()`

Answer (score 7):

```
row = session.query(User.username, User.first_name, User.last_name).all()
as_dict = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
```

Comment: or if there are multiple rows with ```all()``` : as_dict = [dict(zip(row.keys(), row) for row in rows])

Comment: Its a problem when column names in a result are the same as in the next example: session.query(TrafficPattern.id,
            FilterGroup.id,
            TrafficPattern.version).all()