# How can I build a dictionary from a SQLAlchemy row, using cell data as keys and values instead of column names?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a Flask API to retrieve information from a Woocommerce database that I cannot modify.

This is one of the tables schema, from which I only need the columns *meta_key* and *meta_value*.

```
MariaDB [<db_name>] DESCRIBE aus_postmeta;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As the column names suggest, the column *meta_key* is a key (for example, *_billing_address*) and then the column *meta_value* stores the billing address string in itself. What I want to do is to build a dictionary (or a set) in which **the keys are *not* the column name, but the value held by *meta_key* and, respectively, the dictionary value is the information stored in *meta_value*.**

This is the query I run to retrieve the columns filtered by id and getting only the needed meta_keys.

```py
#columns is an array of strings

rows = db.session.query(t_aus_postmeta).\
    with_entities(t_aus_postmeta.c.meta_key, t_aus_postmeta.c.meta_value, ).\
        filter(t_aus_postmeta.c.post_id == order_id).\
            filter(t_aus_postmeta.c.meta_key.in_(columns)).\
                all()
```

Using the following code, [as advised in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350902/sqlalchemy-query-all-list-of-tuples-to-dict) to build a dictionary from the `row` object returned by the query:

```py
# Returns a list with a dictionary, but both keys and values are tuples

>>>> as_dict = [dict(zip(row.keys(), row) for row in rows)]
[{('meta_key', '_billing_shipment'): ('meta_value', 'Recupérate pronto'), ('meta_key', '_order_total'): ('meta_value', '134000')}]
```

But I want to take the value in `meta_key` and *use it* as the dictionary key. Respectively, take the value in `meta_value` and use it as that key's corresponding value, so it would be something like this:

```py
{
    "_billing_shipment": "Recupérate pronto",
    "_order_total": "134000"
    # and so on...
}
```

I've been struggling with this problem but haven't found a way to build the dictionary as I need it. How can I do it? Looking at the tuples returned by the code above, I feel there must be a way to do something like `tuple.meta_key` (for the dictionary key) and `tuple.meta_value`, but I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
dict = {result.meta_key: result.meta_value for result in results}
```

It was much easier than I thought it was.

Comment: I'd love to see the full context of this solution. What all was required before declaring `dict`?